# Issue about using Async with an Android Client

Tags: android, client, android-asynctask

I am currently creating a project that needs to have a simple async task to take care of a thread running behind the scenes. The user needs to login. I am using another class called PVAndroid Client that supplies useful methods and has an XML serializer form packets for me. I am completely new to working with threads or doing anything with servers, so this may be completely wrong or somewhat right.

I get the data the user entered: the ip address and port, their username (I split this into first and last name), their region they selected. I encrypt their password, and attempt to connect to the tcp using ip address and port number. I am trying to work in the async task but am kind of confused on what I should do. Can anyone guide me in the right direction and help me out?

Thank you I really appreciate it.

```
    private TcpClient myTcpClient = null;
    private UdpClient udpClient;
    private static final String USERNAME_SHARED_PREFS = "username";
    private static final String PASSWORD_SHARED_PREFS = "password";
    private static final String IP_ADDRESS_SHARED_PREFS = "ipAddressPref";
    private static final String PORT_SHARED_PREFS = "portNumberPref";
    private String encryptedNameLoginActivity, encryptPassLoginActivity;
    private EditText userText, passText;
    private String getIpAddressSharedPrefs, getPortNumberPrefs;
    private String getUserNameValue;
    private String getPasswordValue;
    private String fName, lName;
    private SharedPreferences settings;
    private Editor myEditor;
    private boolean getCheckedRemember;
    private boolean resultCheck = false;
    private int portNum;
    private Button submitButton;
    private String userMACVARIABLE = "";
    private String regionSelected, gridSelected;
    private Spinner regSpinner, gridSpinner;
    PVDCAndroidClient client;
    private int userNum;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        client = new PVDCAndroidClient();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // Take care of getting user's login information:
        submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
        userText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameTextBox);
        passText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordTextBox);
        regSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.regionSpinner);

        // grid selected as well? sometime?
        regSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long rowId) {
                regionSelected = regSpinner.getItemAtPosition(position)
                        .toString();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                settings = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(AndroidClientCompnt.this);

                getIpAddressSharedPrefs = settings.getString(
                        IP_ADDRESS_SHARED_PREFS, "");
                portNum = Integer.parseInt(settings.getString(
                        PORT_SHARED_PREFS, ""));

                if (getIpAddressSharedPrefs.length() != 0 && portNum != 0) {
                    if (userText.length() != 0 && passText.length() != 0) {
                        try {

                            try {
                                // encrypting the user's password.
                                encryptPassLoginActivity = Secure.encrypt(passText
                                        .toString());
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            // first connect attempt.
                            myTcpClient = new TcpClient();
                            myTcpClient.connect(getIpAddressSharedPrefs,
                                    portNum);
                            // here is where I want to call Async to do login
                            // or do whatever else.

                            UploadTask task = new UploadTask();
                            task.execute();


                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Could not connect.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        });
    }

    private class UploadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> 
    {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Loading...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... names) {

                    resultCheck = myTcpClient.connect(getIpAddressSharedPrefs,
                            portNum);


                    if (resultCheck == true) {
                        while (myTcpClient.getUserNum() < 0) {
                            // num set? session? with proxy server?
                        }

                        String[] firstAndLast;

                        String spcDelmt = " ";

                        firstAndLast = userText.toString().split(spcDelmt);

                        fName = firstAndLast[0];
                        lName = firstAndLast[1];

                        // set up the tcp client to sent the information to the
                        // server.
                        client.login(fName, lName, encryptPassLoginActivity,regionSelected, 128, 128, 20);

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Connection not successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String...params) {
    new Thread (new Runnable() {
       // ...
    }
}
```

Never do this again. There is no need to create new `Thread` in *doInBackground* method which actually running on *background* `Thread`. So remove it.

The advice to you is tricky because you need to read about `Threads`, work with `Connection` etc. So the best advice to you is to read some `tutorials`, examples of basic applications and read references. So you can start here:

[`Android TCP Client and Server Communication Programming–Illustrated with Example`](http://www.roman10.net/android-tcp-client-and-server-communication-programmingillustrated-with-example/)

Comment: I have edited my code some after reading your suggestions and took out the extra runnable code, and added a call to my Async Task. Is this close at all? Again I am new at this, so at this point anything would be very helpful. Here is my edited code: changed around 4:09PM.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see, where you are yoursing your Task, but I see that you are doing something weired inside `doInBackground()`! There is absolutely NO reason, to create your own Thread inside it.
remove that, and you could just use your Task like this:

```
UploadTask task = new UploadTask();
task.execute("someString", "anotherString", "addAsManyStringsYouNeed");
```

The docs from [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) are very helpfull, too.